# Jquery cookie to remember last state of drop down menu

Tags: jquery, cookies, drop-down-menu

Can anyone help me with this, I can't find a script on the internet that does this in jQuery.  I need to remember the last state of drop down menu so that on page load the drop down option is already selected. The cookie expiration date should be 90 days or let me specify in the script. Since I already use jQuery on my page I want this cookie script to use jquery, jquery cookie plugin.  Thank you in advance. I'm not a programmer, but I try.

```
<body onLoad="GETcookie()">
<select onChange="SETcookie()">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: *Ahem.* You do NOT need jQuery to manage cookies. Just find a *Javascript* setup to manage it for you. `</rant>`

Comment: And read this, there are useful functions toward the end: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: (*Although I do kinda wish that the jQuery library would include a `$.cookie()` function that worked like `$.data()`, because cookies are a bit of a pain in the butt in Javascript.* `</zip>`)

Comment: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the plugin that I've included, you can get and set cookies.

Your code would look a little something like this:

```
//checks if the cookie has been set

if($.cookie('remember_select') != null) {

    // set the option to selected that corresponds to what the cookie is set to

    $('.select_class option[value="' + $.cookie('remember_select') + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');

}

// when a new option is selected this is triggered

$('.select_class').change(function() {

    // new cookie is set when the option is changed

    $.cookie('remember_select', $('.select_class option:selected').val(), { expires: 90, path: '/'});

});
```

Here is what you `select` would look like:

```
<select class="select_class">
    <option value="1">Row 1</option>
    <option value="2">Row 2</option>
    <option value="3">Row 3</option>
</select>
```

Here's a demo of it on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RastaLulz/3HxCF/3/

Here's the jQuery cookie plugin incase you don't already have it: http://pastebin.com/CBueT8LP

Comment: Amazing. Have been looking for something like this for 3 days now

Comment: This works great with only on select box but if there are multiple select boxes it only remembers the first one. Can this code work for multiple select boxes?

Answer (score 1):

First don't do body onLoad (should be onload in lowercase), but in my example you don't need your onload and onchange
but :

```
// This replace onload
$(function() {
  // Read your cookie and other things up to you to do...
  $.cookie('the_cookie');

  // on change of your select
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    // Set the cookie
    $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 90, path: '/'});
  });

});
```

PS: my script is jQuery 1.7 (for the on) so look if you are up to date !

Edit: Set the 90 days expires

Comment: Can you give me an example in http://jsfiddle.net because I tried and did not work. Again not a programmer, must have messed up somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: Josh Foskett just did one on http://jsfiddle.net/RastaLulz/3HxCF/3/ you can look at it it works.